# C# Unable to show data even the date is fall within the date range

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm using C# Window Application to pull data from Microsoft Access by using SQL Query for some checking.

I had 2 Table to be compare and select the data.

- Table 1 : USER_OF_RUN which consist of a StartDate and EndDate
- Table 2 : USERINFO which i need to join with Table 1 and pull the
  data    which fall in the date range of StartDate and EndDate table.

If my Table 1's StartDate and EndDate is set from 1/1/2016 to 31/12/2017, all the data are correct. But when the range is set like for example 22/12/2016 to 31/12/2017, and my data that wanted to pull is from date 3/1/2017 which is fall in between of the date range, but somehow the data was empty.

I'm curios is that my Query is wrong or i missing some syntax.

Here are my SQL query :

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(A.CHECKTIME,'dd/mm/yyyy') AS CHECKTIME,
    A.USERID AS USERID, 
    B.NAME AS NAME, 
    B.BADGENUMBER AS BADGENUMBER, 
    C.NUM_OF_RUN_ID, 
    D.NAME AS DEPT, 
    DEFAULTDEPTID 
FROM ((((CHECKINOUT A ) 
    LEFT JOIN USERINFO B 
        ON A.USERID = B.USERID ) 
    LEFT JOIN USER_OF_RUN C 
        ON A.USERID = C.USERID ) 
    LEFT JOIN NUM_RUN D 
        ON C.NUM_OF_RUN_ID = D.NUM_RUNID ) 
WHERE 
    Format(A.CHECKTIME, 'dd/mm/yyyy') IN (Format('03/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), Format(DateAdd('d', 1, Format('03/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')), 'dd/mm/yyyy')) 
    AND Format('03/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') BETWEEN Format(C.STARTDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND Format(C.ENDDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
    AND DEFAULTDEPTID = 4 
    AND BADGENUMBER = '7092'
ORDER BY A.USERID DESC, CHECKTIME asc 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    distinct '', 
    USERID, 
    NAME, 
    BADGENUMBER, 
    '',
    '',
    '' 
FROM USERINFO 
WHERE userid NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT A.USERID AS USERID 
     FROM ((((CHECKINOUT A) 
         LEFT JOIN USERINFO B 
             ON A.USERID = B.USERID ) 
         LEFT JOIN USER_OF_RUN C 
             ON A.USERID = C.USERID ) 
         LEFT JOIN NUM_RUN D 
             ON C.NUM_OF_RUN_ID = D.NUM_RUNID ) 
     WHERE Format (A.CHECKTIME, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = Format('03/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
         AND Format('03/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') BETWEEN Format(C.STARTDATE, 'dd/mm/yy') AND Format(C.ENDDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy')) 
         AND DEFAULTDEPTID = 4 
         AND BADGENUMBER = '7092'
```

Comment: Your query is unreadable on a single line like that - and even if it weren't, it's far more complex than it needs to be. Please reduce this to a *minimal* query. (Have you tried querying without a join at all?)

Comment: I am under the impression you are storing your dates as strings. Am I right?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the suggest, i had edit the code. Can it be more easy to see now?

Comment: @Steve Yes, my date was choose from datetime picker and i was turning it to string and input it into the query. But the query is working fine if i change the StartDate to 1st of Any month

Comment: Why are you formatting string constants?  Also you don't want to use `Between` on the string representation of a date as it will do a string comparison instead of a data comparison.

Comment: Well at least we can see it - but it's still *enormous* (and completely unformatted). Please, please, please reduce this to a minimal example.

Comment: And as Steve is hinting, storing dates as strings is a really, really bad idea - especially given that you're not storing them in a sortable order! (Lexically, the string "01/01/2020" comes before "10/01/2016" - but you don't want that...)

Comment: @JonSkeet What do you mean the string "01/01/2020" comes before "10/01/2016" ??

Comment: Adding to what @JonSkeet said, if you're storing your dates as string, then you should cast them to date before comparing them

Comment: @MarcusZac: Um, exactly that - in the same way that the string "abc" comes before "bcd". When you're comparing *strings*, you basically look a t the first character first... and '0' comes before '1'. (It's a bit more complicated than that, but fundamentally it shows the problem.)

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake my date time was not string, it use to be DateTime GetDateFrom = fromDate.Value.Date; In which it was a datetime data type instead of string

Comment: @JonSkeet I putting the sample above just to let you guys know what is exactly data input on the sql query for selecting data only. The actual datatype for the date is datetime which is not as early you guys mention string type

Comment: If the columns in question are indeed `Date/Time` columns then jettison all of the `Format()` gymnastics and simply use the Date values as dates. Also, use a *parameterized query* to avoid problems with localized date formats. (Hint: The Access Database Engine does not always respect the Windows locale settings and can often interpret '03/01/2017' as March 1 instead of January 3, even if your Windows user settings are configured for a `dd/mm/yyyy` Short Date display.)

Comment: Please do describe table_name for both your tables and update your question with the result.

Comment: @GordThompson Hi, if i removed all Format(), my sql query does not seem to work which show syntax error now

Comment: Please re-read the very first comment from @JonSkeet. Try reducing your query to a single-table [mcve] and concentrate on getting that working, then expand it to involve JOINs and UNIONs and other fancy things. You need to learn to walk before you can run.

Comment: @GordThompson I had try with minimal on my code, still same no result show

Comment: If if the type is DateTime in your database, that's what your query should use too. Once you've come up with a *simple* query trying to use that, it will be easy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel you can reduce the query to debug it, at least get the date parts right:

```
SELECT 
    A.CHECKTIME,
    A.USERID, 
    B.NAME, 
    B.BADGENUMBER, 
    C.NUM_OF_RUN_ID, 
    D.NAME AS DEPT, 
    DEFAULTDEPTID 
FROM ((((CHECKINOUT A ) 
    LEFT JOIN USERINFO B 
        ON A.USERID = B.USERID ) 
    LEFT JOIN USER_OF_RUN C 
        ON A.USERID = C.USERID ) 
    LEFT JOIN NUM_RUN D 
        ON C.NUM_OF_RUN_ID = D.NUM_RUNID ) 
WHERE 
    A.CHECKTIME = #2017/01/03# 
    AND 
    #2017/01/03# BETWEEN C.STARTDATE AND C.ENDDATE 
    AND 
    DEFAULTDEPTID = 4 
    AND 
    BADGENUMBER = '7092'
ORDER BY A.USERID DESC, A.CHECKTIME ASC

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    '', 
    USERID, 
    NAME, 
    BADGENUMBER, 
    '',
    '',
    '' 
FROM USERINFO 
WHERE USERID NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT A.USERID AS USERID 
     FROM ((((CHECKINOUT A) 
         LEFT JOIN USERINFO B 
             ON A.USERID = B.USERID ) 
         LEFT JOIN USER_OF_RUN C 
             ON A.USERID = C.USERID ) 
         LEFT JOIN NUM_RUN D 
             ON C.NUM_OF_RUN_ID = D.NUM_RUNID ) 
     WHERE 
         A.CHECKTIME = #2017/01/03# 
         AND 
         #2017/01/03# BETWEEN C.STARTDATE AND C.ENDDATE 
         AND 
         DEFAULTDEPTID = 4 
         AND 
         BADGENUMBER = '7092'
```

If your date fields contain a time part, wrap these in *DateValue* or *Fix*.